# Internet Explorer 11 adds values to Typescript Map in Post Request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11

I'm working on a little private project with an Angular Frontend and a Java Backend and I recently found some weird IE11 behaviour with it (I know IE11 is horrible and should not be used with Angular projects). At one point I send a POST to my backend server with a Map Payload.I know that IE11 support of TS Maps is only partial. I had no problems receiving Maps from the Backend, but when I send a Map I get a deserialition Error:

```
ERROR Can not deserialize Map key of type [...] from String "_t": not a valid representation[...]
```

The backend expects the keys of the Map to be names of an Enum. I understand that the error tells me that he could not map `_t` to a value of the Enum, which is not surprising as the Enum does not contain that value.

The weird part is, that I did not put a key/value pair with `_t` in the map. This problem does not appear with Firefox/Chrome. Did some debugging and found that IE11 seems to add some key/value pairs to the Map.

```
  mapName: {
     [functions]: ,
     __proto__: { },
     _f: undefined,
     _i: { },
     _l: undefined,
     _s: 0,
     _t: "Map",
     size: 0,
     CAT: 4
  },
```

The only thing I added to the Map is `CAT: 4`.

Surprisingly I did not find references to this problem. Is there a fix to this problem? Except adding those values to the Backend Enum and ignore them?

Comment: Please check the polyfill.ts file and make sure you have uncomment the related import for the IE browser, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXSUp.png). Besides, you could also check the ES version, and try to use ES6.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: @shutdown-hnow Not really, just a little workaround by setting those values and ignoring them. So in the frontend you'd set `yourMap.set('_t', 'someValue')` and then ignore it in the backend.

Comment: ok i just remapped this object using regex start with '_'

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT I'm running into this problem and I have the map polyfill enabled :/

Answer (score 0):

To fix it I just stopped using map and used a typed dictionary instead:

```
controllerProperty: {[keyOrWhatever:string]: string}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try the following define to replacing your new map（）.

var mapName={
     CAT: 4
  }；

Comment: Sure, that sidesteps the problem, but it doesn't solve the issue. Presumably the code works fine as-is on other browsers. What can be done to get it to work on IE 11?